# Where and when does this view get populated with data?

Tags: php, mysql, view

I've recently been handed a Yii project (PHP) developed by another developer and I've been assigned to take over it's maintenance.

In the database there is the following VIEW that holds data for certain records in other tables. **The view gets -somehow- updated frequently as it contains recent records, meaning that somewhere/somehow rows are constantly being added to it.** 
However, it's not being referenced as part of the project, meaning it's not defined in a model, controller or anywhere else inside the project whatsoever. I've also gone through the database triggers to see where this view gets its data from but I fail to connect the ends.
I thought there might be a cron job that adds data to it but nada.

So, I'm pretty stuck and in awe. Any ideas on how I could find WHEN this views is either dropped and recreated or where I can find which database action functions as a trigger for inserting rows to it?

```
DELIMITER $$

ALTER ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`user_name`@`` SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW `VW_viewname` AS 
SELECT
  `DOM`.`CustomerID`    AS `CustomerID`,
  `DOM`.`User`          AS `User`,
  `DOM`.`DemoOrderDate` AS `DemoOrderDate`
FROM `Demo_Orders_M` `DOM`
WHERE (`DOM`.`DemoOrderStatus` = 253)
GROUP BY `DOM`.`CustomerID`
HAVING (COUNT(`DOM`.`CustomerID`) > 1)$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Is it in an .sh script running on the server itself called via php somewhere?

Comment: Unfortunatelly, no. I ran a grep command from linux command line to find any file that contains the name of the view and it came up with nothing.

Comment: "Prior to MySQL 5.0.72, when you modify an existing view, the server saves a backup of the current view definition under the view database directory, in a subdirectory named arc. The backup file for a view v is named v.frm-00001. If you alter the view again, the next backup is named v.frm-00002. The three latest view backup definitions are stored. " https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html Not sure if it helps but maybe you can find something there.

Comment: Interesting, I'll have a look.

Comment: Maybe performing a grep with a query field, like 'DemoOrderDate' on all files of your directory/project?